# Foundation for Emails won't compile for production - SCSS folder not being created

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

This is my first project with Foundation for Emails. When I run `foundation build`, I get:

```
[17:42:43] Starting 'inline'...
Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Repositories\email-template\dist\assets\scss'
    at Error (native)

[17:42:44] The following tasks did not complete: default, build, inline
[17:42:44] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

It looks like it's failing because the SCSS folder is not being generated.

Everything works fine when I run `foundation watch`.

How can I troubleshoot this further and learn why the SCSS folder isn't being created?

This is on a Windows machine, through Powershell. I've tried commenting out all of my custom SCSS code, leaving only the three `@import` statements at the top of app.scss. I've also tried deleting my node_modules folder and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was that I had this line at the top of my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss">
```